# Excel 2007: How to replace part of formula with another formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to replace the **$D49** with

```
SERROR(VLOOKUP($B49 & " Total",Flt_S2D1,$Z$47,0)),0,VLOOKUP($B49 & " Total",Flt_S2D1,$Z$47,0))** in below formula.

=IFERROR(IF($Z$38="CBO Dmd",$C49,IF($Z$38="CBO Dmd-Cust Raw",$D49*($Y49/$E49),IF($Z$38="CBO Dmd-Pr CBO",$D49*($X49/$E49),IF($Z$38="CBO Dmd-BAB Grs CGID",$D49*($W49/$E49),IF($Z$38="CBO Dmd-Bill Grs CGID",$D49*($V49/$E49),$D49*($CC49/$E49)))))),0)
```

I have googled and find some articles to do this, but those are related to replacing a part of formula with calculated result or cell value.

I can replace  **$D49** with required value by doing multiple times, but is there any way to replace at a time like **find and replace all**, which we are doing for text replace.

Answer (score 6):

Normal Search and Replace works (shortcut Ctrl+H). Just make sure you choose 'Look in:' **Formulas**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can still do search and replace on cells with a formula. It will be applied to the forumla, not the result you see. Try it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution doesnt require any additional VBA code and will work with Google Spreadsheet and almost all versions of Excel.**

Its relatively easy to do complex fine and replace in multiple excel cells using a combination of `VIM`, `Excel` and notepad. Because VIM can do very complex search and replace operations, you can pretty much do almost search and replace with this method.

If you have `vim` installed on windows, you don’t need notepad. Assumes `Excel` is installed on `Windows`

### Steps

1. Press `Ctrl-``, to change the displayed values to formulas (https://www.thoughtco.com/show-hide-formulas-in-excel-and-google-spreadsheets-3123884)
2. Copy the formulas from excel
3. Copy the formulae into VIM: press `i` while in `normal` mode in `vim`. Press `Shift-Insert` and `Escape`
4. Use `ex` mode search and replace with `Regular expressions` to do search and replace by pressing `:%s/old/new/gc`. Here old is the part of the expression you want to substitute and `new` is the new `formula` you want to substitute with. https://stackoverflow.com/a/505861/4752883
5. Make sure to do a `%s/[[:space:]]*//gc` to remove any blank spaces in front of each line in `ex` mode in `vim`
6. Save the file as a `.txt` file, if you are using `vim` in linux.
7. Copy the formula from the `.txt` file by pressing `Ctrl-A` and `Ctrl-V` and enter it into the first cell